# Firebase set method not adding data to an existing Collection

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am using VUEX and Firebase to create a register form with three fields NAME, EMAIL, PASSWORD. First i am using createUserWithEmailAndPassword method to add the user but I also want to ad the name filed data to an Existing Blank collection, here I am using set method. But it is not adding the name field data in the collection.

```
methods: {
onSignUp() {
        firebase
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
        .then(user => {
            console.log(user);
            console.log(user.user.uid);

            firebase.database.collection("profiles").doc(user.user.id).set({
                name: this.name
            })
            .then(function() {
                console.log("Document successfully written!");
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
            });

            this.$store.dispatch('signUserUp', user);

        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.$store.dispatch('signUserError', error)
        });
    }
}

data(){
  return {
    name: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
  }
}
```

After submitting the form it's adding a new user and I can also see the uid in the console but some how its not updating the name field in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `firebase.firestore()` and not `firebase.database` (See this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Firestore)) and therefore adapt your code as follows:

```
onSignUp() {
        firebase
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
        .then(user => {
            console.log(user);
            console.log(user.user.uid);

            return firebase.firestore().collection("profiles").doc(user.user.id).set({
                name: this.name
            });
         })
         .then(() => {
             console.log("Document successfully written!");
             this.$store.dispatch('signUserUp', user);
         })
        .catch(error => {
            this.$store.dispatch('signUserError', error)
        });
    }
}
```

---

You should also check that your security rules for the `profiles` collection are correctly set. Normally (authenticated) users should only be able to write a document with their own `userid` as document id.